# Javascript triggering CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I don't know how to put this but please have a look at my code:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imsy041/LccLzb9v/)

```
.pie:nth-of-type(1):hover:AFTER,
.pie:nth-of-type(1):hover:BEFORE  {
    background-color:yellow;    
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

its basically a wheel of fortune game but using highlight instead of spinning.

the question is how do i write a javascript that triggers the event that highlight the slices throughout a given amount of time? also i would like the transition speed between each slices to slow down over the time.

Comment: I was curious, did you solve the issue of hover in your CSS for the first couple of segments? See this derived fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/he5wg7jb/

Comment: er it doesn't matter anyway because i will be using javascript to trigger the highlight without even hovering. thank you for your time anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple.

First, you don't need all the `n-th-of-type` for all the pies. But you need an extra class, say, 'active', otherwise you cannot highlight it via JavaScript.

So, you .pie CSS becomes:

```
.pie.active:BEFORE,
.pie:hover:AFTER,
.pie:hover:BEFORE {
   background-color: yellow;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Then, here is the example code that does what you need (in onload):

```
function highlight(el, delay) {
  setTimeout(function() {
     el.className += ' active'; //light it up
     //un-highlight after delay:
     setTimeout(function() {  el.className = 'pie'; }, 200)
  }, delay)
}


var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.pie');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  highlight(divs[i], i*200);
}
```

Here is the fiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2k8x7rkt/4/)

It can be made a bit more smooth by addition transitions, e.g. add `transition: background-color 0.1s;` to the above CSS and make all programmatic delays 200ms.

To implement slow downs, you need to play with the delay formula. `i*200` is rather simplistic, but I don't want to take away the fun to try various math functions to change timing. Additionally, you can change `transition` css, changing it programmatically on the element itself takes precedence over CSS. You can easily make it fairly realistic after some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wayfkdqf/)

What you need to do is have some javascript that adds and removes your hover class based on a timer.
Pseudocode below:

```
if spinTime < desiredSpinTime
  remove hover class from previous element
  get next element
  add hover class to next element

  add time step to spinTime
  get next time step
  call this function again with a delay of the next time step
```